# Is there a way to tell if someone has gone through all slides of a presentation on sharepoint

Tags: 2010, powerpoint-services

Basically what I am trying to do is to put some training presentations onto our SharePoint, that our engineers go through and read.

I've set a test site up and have been able to work out how to capture that the presentations have been opened.

However I want to know to find out if there is a way to show that they have actually gone through the whole presentation, instead of just opening and then closing it.

Answer (score 3):

Once the presentation is opened in PowerPoint, SharePoint is no longer in control. To establish whether a presentation has been watched from start to finish would require some monitoring code within the presentation, if it is doable at all.

An alternative might be to convert the PPT to a series of html files and jazz these up with javascript and/or cookies to keep track of a user's reading history.

None of these approaches are specific to SharePoint, though, and they don't involve SharePoint technology.

Also, please look at http://www.excelguru.ca/node/7